# Can I infer a tuple type from a function's return type, without using 'as const'?

Tags: typescript

I want to use a function that constructs an array as an argument, where each element may be a different type. The order of types is relevant and I need to preserve their order as a Tuple. Here is one way:

```
const create = <T>(spec: (...args: any[]) => T) => spec;
const result = create(() => ['a', 2, 'a'] as const);
type t = ReturnType<typeof result>; // t is ['a', 2, 'a']
```

However, this means the developer has to remember to add `as const` every time they use `create`.

In my use case, the order of types is *always* relevant and the function should always receive a Tuple.

Is there any way to force Typescript to always infer the Tuple from the return type without needing `as const`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hint to the compiler that a generic type argument should be inferred as a tuple type if you specify the constraint of it as `[any] | any[]`.

```
const create = <T extends [any] | any[]>(spec: (...args: any[]) => T) => spec;
const result = create(() => ['a', 2, 'a']);
type t = ReturnType<typeof result>; // t is [string, number, string]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRMC8MA8AVGiAHmmACYQwDayYAngLowA+MNtl9AfABQQAOiYAC4Y3AHQTk8AOYQRbDgEpMnGLmUZV-QQG4AsAChQkWEggBXADawsCFGm7cNqygHJkrgDQwATN-eu9Ir6BlC0AjA2MABKiFDm8GC44YjYYQIgAGYwZlZQnDowAPRFkTAAlhRuHt5+MAH0QA)

---

It doesn't seem possible to infer the literal constant such as `['a', 2, 'a']`.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks very much!

Comment: Heya, I realised that this actually doesn't return the const literals 'a', 2, 'a'... but [string, number, string]

Comment: @SebastianNemeth yeah you are right, sorry about that.. can't really find a way to preserve literals in this case unfortunately, my usual tricks don't work for the return type for some reason

Comment: Yeah I've come to the same conclusion... I'll update your answer and mark it so.